# How to stop JAXB qualifying attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I get JAXB to qualify only elements, and not attributes?

I've got the following, which is correctly qualifying elements with the given prefix. However, it's also qualifying the attributes with that prefix, which is not required.

```
@XmlSchema(xmlns = {@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = "atom") }, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNSET)
```

It yields this:

```
<atom:link atom:rel="self" atom:href="/accounts/123456XZ" atom:type="application/xml"></atom:link>
```

I've tried both XmlNsForm.UNSET and UNQUALIFIED, and both have the same result.

What I'd like is this:

```
<atom:link rel="self" href="/accounts/123456XZ" type="application/xml"></atom:link>
```

Here's the class in question, as generated by XJC from an XSD:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2013.08.19 at 12:28:23 PM BST 
//


package org.w3._2005.atom;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import net.karneim.pojobuilder.GeneratePojoBuilder;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.Equals;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.EqualsStrategy;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.JAXBEqualsStrategy;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.JAXBToStringStrategy;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.ToString;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.ToStringStrategy;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.ObjectLocator;
import org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.locator.util.LocatorUtils;


/**
 * 
 *                 The Atom link construct is defined in section 3.4 of the format spec.
 *             
 * 
 * <p>Java class for linkType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="linkType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;attGroup ref="{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}commonAttributes"/>
 *       &lt;attribute name="rel" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="href" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyURI" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="type" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="hreflang" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}NMTOKEN" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="title" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="length" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}positiveInteger" />
 *       &lt;anyAttribute namespace='##other'/>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "linkType", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@GeneratePojoBuilder
public class LinkType
    implements Equals, ToString
{

    @XmlValue
    protected String content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "rel")
    protected String rel;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "href", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String href;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    protected String type;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "hreflang")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "NMTOKEN")
    protected String hreflang;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "title")
    protected String title;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "length")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "positiveInteger")
    protected BigInteger length;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "base", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String base;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "language")
    protected String lang;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    /**
     * 
     *                 The Atom link construct is defined in section 3.4 of the format spec.
     *             
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setContent(String value) {
        this.content = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the rel property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getRel() {
        return rel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the rel property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setRel(String value) {
        this.rel = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setHref(String value) {
        this.href = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the type property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setType(String value) {
        this.type = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the hreflang property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getHreflang() {
        return hreflang;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the hreflang property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setHreflang(String value) {
        this.hreflang = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the title property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the title property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTitle(String value) {
        this.title = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the length property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public BigInteger getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the length property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public void setLength(BigInteger value) {
        this.length = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the base property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the base property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setBase(String value) {
        this.base = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lang property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lang property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLang(String value) {
        this.lang = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }

    public String toString() {
        final ToStringStrategy strategy = JAXBToStringStrategy.INSTANCE;
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        append(null, buffer, strategy);
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public StringBuilder append(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
        strategy.appendStart(locator, this, buffer);
        appendFields(locator, buffer, strategy);
        strategy.appendEnd(locator, this, buffer);
        return buffer;
    }

    public StringBuilder appendFields(ObjectLocator locator, StringBuilder buffer, ToStringStrategy strategy) {
        {
            String theContent;
            theContent = this.getContent();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "content", buffer, theContent);
        }
        {
            String theRel;
            theRel = this.getRel();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "rel", buffer, theRel);
        }
        {
            String theHref;
            theHref = this.getHref();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "href", buffer, theHref);
        }
        {
            String theType;
            theType = this.getType();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "type", buffer, theType);
        }
        {
            String theHreflang;
            theHreflang = this.getHreflang();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "hreflang", buffer, theHreflang);
        }
        {
            String theTitle;
            theTitle = this.getTitle();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "title", buffer, theTitle);
        }
        {
            BigInteger theLength;
            theLength = this.getLength();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "length", buffer, theLength);
        }
        {
            String theBase;
            theBase = this.getBase();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "base", buffer, theBase);
        }
        {
            String theLang;
            theLang = this.getLang();
            strategy.appendField(locator, this, "lang", buffer, theLang);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public boolean equals(ObjectLocator thisLocator, ObjectLocator thatLocator, Object object, EqualsStrategy strategy) {
        if (!(object instanceof LinkType)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        final LinkType that = ((LinkType) object);
        {
            String lhsContent;
            lhsContent = this.getContent();
            String rhsContent;
            rhsContent = that.getContent();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "content", lhsContent), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "content", rhsContent), lhsContent, rhsContent)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsRel;
            lhsRel = this.getRel();
            String rhsRel;
            rhsRel = that.getRel();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "rel", lhsRel), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "rel", rhsRel), lhsRel, rhsRel)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsHref;
            lhsHref = this.getHref();
            String rhsHref;
            rhsHref = that.getHref();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "href", lhsHref), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "href", rhsHref), lhsHref, rhsHref)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsType;
            lhsType = this.getType();
            String rhsType;
            rhsType = that.getType();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "type", lhsType), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "type", rhsType), lhsType, rhsType)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsHreflang;
            lhsHreflang = this.getHreflang();
            String rhsHreflang;
            rhsHreflang = that.getHreflang();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "hreflang", lhsHreflang), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "hreflang", rhsHreflang), lhsHreflang, rhsHreflang)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsTitle;
            lhsTitle = this.getTitle();
            String rhsTitle;
            rhsTitle = that.getTitle();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "title", lhsTitle), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "title", rhsTitle), lhsTitle, rhsTitle)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            BigInteger lhsLength;
            lhsLength = this.getLength();
            BigInteger rhsLength;
            rhsLength = that.getLength();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "length", lhsLength), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "length", rhsLength), lhsLength, rhsLength)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsBase;
            lhsBase = this.getBase();
            String rhsBase;
            rhsBase = that.getBase();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "base", lhsBase), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "base", rhsBase), lhsBase, rhsBase)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        {
            String lhsLang;
            lhsLang = this.getLang();
            String rhsLang;
            rhsLang = that.getLang();
            if (!strategy.equals(LocatorUtils.property(thisLocator, "lang", lhsLang), LocatorUtils.property(thatLocator, "lang", rhsLang), lhsLang, rhsLang)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        final EqualsStrategy strategy = JAXBEqualsStrategy.INSTANCE;
        return equals(null, null, object, strategy);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have specified the `namespace` parameter on the `@XmlAttribute` annotation as follows:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Link {

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    private String rel;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    private String href;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    private String type;

}
```

What you need to do for your use case is the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Link {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String rel;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String href;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I've included the generated class, which doesn't appear to include the offending XML annotations. Any ideas?